# Burning Plastic: can it be done without harmful pollution?

Tags: hydrocarbons, plastics, environmental-chemistry, ozone, green-chemistry

Can plastic be melted, incinerated or recycled without emitting harmful gases and CO2? Specifically, can this be done without releasing gases harmful to humans?

This question pertains to the melting performed during initial product production (in molds) and later during the recycling state.

I ask because I see differing positions on whether it’s more environmentally friendly to bury vs incinerate. I’m also curious how factories that mold plastic from those pellets insure there is no air pollution. Maybe some exhaust devices capture the harmful gases. Very curious because I visited Thailand once where there were factories and it smelled like burning plastic outside.

Hoping to hear a chemistry viewpoint.

Comment: CO2 does not impact ozone layer.

Comment: Many plastics that can be safely  burnt are better to be recycled.

Comment: You cannot burn something containing carbon without producing carbon dioxide.

Comment: Even many simple plastics containing C, H and O (PET, PP, PE, PS) which might be thought to be burnable to CO2 and water are not easy to burn because of the other additives in the actual plastic. Many contain plasticisers and flame retardants and other additives that will generate much more toxic emissions when burned.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly depends on the kind of plastic you burn. As long as they do not contain any elements besides carbon, hydrogen, oxygen and nitrogen and given that you provide enough oxygen to the combustion process there is not real problem and the only combustion products will be water, carbon dioxide and nitrogen.

So, plastics like PE, PP, PET, polyesters, polyamides and so on are not something to  worry about. Much more challenging are plastics that contain elements like chlorine (PVC), fluorine (PTFE, PFA) or sulfur (rubber) because they can produce toxic gases when burned.

Comment: You can't exactly "burn" PTFE. Also burning polyamides  is a terrible idea unless you have something like industrial grade furnace.

Comment: So PVC, PTFE and sulfur are the plastics the other poster here states release harmful fumes (the ones I typically hear are bad for humans to breath)?

Comment: Also for PVC, PTFE and sulfur are there capture mechanisms for the harmful gases?  I still think of my experience in Thailand where I could smell burnt plastic in the air after leaving Bangkok and wonder if it was due to manufacturing (which is why I was there).

Answer (score 2):

Usually burning plastics is not recommended as it can emits harmful fumes like carbon monoxide, nitrogen oxides, carbon dioxide, heavy metals like lead, mercury, arsenic and carcinogens like dioxins, furans, polychlorinated biphenyls (PCBs), brominated polyaromatic hydrocarbons (PAHS) but there are still incinerators that burn plastics and the heat generated is converted to electricity (as a form of recycling energy). You can check below articles:

- https://oceana.ca/en/blog/burning-plastic-is-not-a-recycling-solution-its-more-pollution/
- https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/article/should-we-burn-plastic-waste
- https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-43120041
- https://flo-bro.com/burn-plastics/

However, scientists and researches are figuring out a way to burn plastics in a more greener way. In one article<sup>ref</sup>, researchers at have come up with a process named **pyrolytic gasification**. Instead of directly burning the plastic in open air, their reactor will heats the material to 800 °C *in a completely oxygen-free environment*. This causes the plastic to become a gas, which is then mixed with air before it is burned as a clean fuel free of oxygen-free organics like dioxins and furan.

The patent-pending process has one more advantage: when the researchers introduced a bit of stainless steel into the reactor, they found it acted as a catalyst for growing uniform carbon nanotubes which can be used in other applications.

**Ref**.: https://phys.org/news/2013-12-plastic-cleanly-natural-gas.html

Comment: Any comments on the initial process of filling molds for products?  Is there some sort of capture device for the gases, especially with PVC, PTFE and sulfur?